# Bold Font is Rendered Wrong

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

When I try to render a Chinese string like 试标记好不好 Graphics.DrawString draws it

[image]

even if I change the Font Linking to SimSun. On the other hand TextRenderer works but it fails to render readable strings when bold fonts are used. It seems there is no correct way to render bold strings.

[image]

The issue is described in greater detail [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2014/12/01/160433.aspx). Am I doing something wrong or does Windows not support professional looking localizable applications with some bold strings in the UI?

The code to repro the issue is for a Windows Forms application with two PictureBoxes:

```
    const string combined = "测试标记好不好This is a aber long";

    private void cFontSize_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(750, 140);
        Font f = new Font("Arial", (float)cFontSize.Value, IsBold ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver;

            // Rendering with a Background Color solves the issue but 
            // this would produce boxes of white or black color in the displayed image which looks even worse
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, combined, f, new Point(0, 0), FontColor);
        }
        cPictureBox.Image = bmp;

        Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(750, 140);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2))
        {
            g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver;
            g.DrawString(combined, f, FontBrush, 0, 0);
        }

        cPicture2.Image = bmp2;
    }
```

**Update 1:**

When I add as Font Link Setting to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink

```
Arial Bold
   SIMSUNB.TTC,SimSun Bold
   MSGOTHIC.TTC,MS UI Gothic
```

then Graphics.DrawString looks ok now althogh TextRender now gets problems. After restarting the application now both outputs look font wise ok although TextRenderer still has the problem that bold fonts become unreadable due to anti aliasing with black. I will restart the machine to check out any caching effects.

Comment: Could you inline the code example so that the issue can be reproduced even if the external site goes offline? Thanks.

Comment: I have added the code sample.

Comment: "or does Windows not support professional looking localizable applications with some bold strings in the UI?" ... the actual issue doesn't seem to be a problem with bold strings on localizable applications. It seems to be a problem with defined font substitution if using bold strings (which may or may not be a problem for professional localizable applications). It seems to be a bug (or a lack of feature), but I'd more carefully choose my wording when voicing these errors.

Comment: Some fonts just don't bold as well.  And some fonts have a separate bold version.

Comment: By the way, the more simple workaround is to use a Unicode complete font, instead of `Arial`. If you directly use `SimSun`, the problem's solved, at least for the example in the link (and if you need Arial, you can use [Arial Unicode MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS) )

Comment: I won`t replace thousands of locations of Arial all over the place with SimSun just to discover that now some Western characters look funny. Font Linking the the feature to enable just that. I will try to add Arial Bold.

Comment: Using SimSun as bold font does not improve the situation at all. The problem is the anti aliasing of TextRenderer which uses black which renders the string nearly unreadable.

Comment: I just made some quick tests and, and at least with WPF, except for Arial Bold (which shows that problem), both Arial Unicode and SimSun look ok to me in Win 8.1: [screenshot](http://oi61.tinypic.com/35d4180.jpg)

Comment: Western typography just doesn't map well to Chinese sensibilities.  7pt type simply isn't readable enough, bold and italic are not used in East Asian typography.  The font designer omits outlines for them.  The synthesized font you get is utterly unreadable at 8 pixel output.  Don't try.

Comment: I would be ok with a 12pt readable Font. There is simply no more space in the UI and it must be transparent. The secondary font linking key for Arial Bold seems to mostly solve the issue although I am not sure which settings are the best ones.

Comment: Interestingly the Arial Bold Font Linking does not work on an English Win 8.1 machine but on my German home machine it works ...